# Как можно сравнить I-й символ в строке с любым непробельным символом?

Tags: c#, label, richtextbox

У меня есть текст из `richTextBox`, сохраненный в строке. Мне нужно узнать количество слов в нем. Конечно, можно воспользоваться `Split()` по пробелам примерно так:

```
 private void countWords() {
            if (richTextBox.Focused)
            {
                String buf = richTextBox.Text;
                int counter = 0;
                buf.Trim();
                counter = buf.Split(' ').Length;
                counterLabel.Text += ' ' + counter.ToString();
                }
            }
```

но хочу отловить случаи, когда в перед следующим словом 2 или больше пробелов. Как Составить такое условие?

```
если i-й символ в тексте пробел, а (i+1) и до следующего пробела — непробельные символы, то увеличить счетчик слов
```

Пробую так :

```
String buf = richTextBox.Text;
int counter = 0;

for (int i =0; i< buf.Length; ++i) {
     if (buf[i].Equals(' ') && buf[i + 1].Equals('\S')) {
         ++counter;
      }
}
```

и мне подчеркивает '\S', как нераспознанную escape-последотельность. Для '\S' обязательно нужно использовать регулярное выражение? Помогите его правильно составить, спасибо.

Comment: Да, обязательно. В строках не особо много escape-последовательностей (типа самых ходовых `\r\n` там редкости с давних времён какие-то колокольчики дзинькают и т.п.). А \S \s \w сразу читать про gerexp'ы

Comment: Эту задачу можно решить и без регулярных выражений, но кода будет больше. Просто нужно учесть то, что между словами может быть больше одного пробельного символа.

Comment: Можешь использовать перегрузку [`Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_) передав [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netcore-3.1) - тогда в результате не будет пустых элементов, от сдвоенных пробелов

Comment: `int count = buf.Split(new [] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length` - готово.

Comment: @aepot, `Split` возвращает массив, можно сразу `.Length` использовать

Comment: @Grundy верно, исправлено :)

Comment: @aepot вы забыли добавить еще символ `'\v'`. И еще один интересный факт: если передать в `Split` в качестве `separator` `null` или пустой массив, то метод в качестве `separator` будет рассматривать все проблельные символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот функционал реализуют [регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(buf,@"\s+");
int wordCount = matches.Count+1
```